# How to reuse one html head section?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, zend-framework

I am using **zend** and not using AJAX in my site. Therefore I have to include all my CSS and JS files in head section of every **phtml** page.

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycssfile.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="myjsfile1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="myjsfile2.js"></script>
  .........
</head>
<body>
  .........
</body>

</html>
```

Whenever I add any new CSS/JS file, I have to include it everywhere. Is there a good way that I can include all my CSS and JS file in a file/place and use that reference everywhere. May be there is a good way in zend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually put my static suff in the bootstrap of the application in the _initViewHelpers method :

```
$this->bootstrap(array('frontcontroller', 'view'));
$frontController = $this->getResource('frontcontroller');
$view = $this->getResource('view');

$view->headLink()->appendStylesheet($view->assetUrl('/css/reset.css'))
                 ->appendStylesheet($view->assetUrl('/css/clearfix.css'))
                 ->appendStylesheet($view->assetUrl('/css/screen.css'));

$view->headScript()->appendFile($view->assetUrl('/js/jquery.1.4.3.min.js', 'text/javascript'))
                   ->appendFile($view->assetUrl('/js/jquery.corner.js', 'text/javascript'));
```

And then from your layout file you call them through

```
echo $this->headLink()->setIndent();
echo $this->headStyle()->setIndent();
```

This site might also help you with bootstrap and application optimization 
http://joegornick.com/2009/11/18/zend-framework-best-practices-part-1-getting-started/

Comment: I tried this. I put above code in `_initAutoload()` function in bootstrap and found following error. `Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'Resource matching "view" not found' in C:\wamp\www\student\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php` Are aware of this error ??

Comment: Try making a new method named _initViewHelpers as said in the first line of the answer

Answer (score 3):

In normal PHP, you would just put the common bits in another template and include it:

```
<?php include 'common/header_assets.php'; ?>

common/header_assets.php:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="myjsfile1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myjsfile1.js"></script>
```

With the Zend Framework, you would want to create a layout for all of your templates to share that would have these common bits:

http://zendframework.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-layout.html